# Is it possible to use multiple slash Django URL as one variable in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I'm new to Django. I'm now creating a project. In that project, I've links like this:

```
https://localhost:8000/example.com/example/path/
```

In the URL the `example.com/example/path/` can be dynamically long as like this

```
example.com
```

or

```
example.com/asset/css/style.css
```

or

```
domain.com/core/content/auth/assets/js/vendor/jquery.js
```

I've used `<str:domainurl>` But is not working. As it has multiple forward slashes. And the forward slashes URL length generated while web **scraping**.
So is there is a way to use the full URL as one variable?

Comment: Can you [url encode](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/utils/#django.utils.http.urlencode) the `domainurl` string? E.g. `https://localhost:8000/example.com%2Fexample%2Fpath%2F`

Answer (score 1):

You want to be using the `path` [path converter [Django docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/urls/#path-converters):

```
path('<path:domainurl>/', some_view)
```

Quoting Django docs:

> **path** - Matches any non-empty string, including the path separator, **'/'**. This allows you to match against a complete URL path rather than a segment of a URL path as with **str**.

> **Note**: Design your url patterns and order them carefully if you are going to use this. Django uses the **first** matching url pattern to
> serve any request.

Comment: I used it but it only takes the `example.com`

Answer (score 0):

If you want Django to match some custom strings take a look at `re_path` (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/urls/#django.urls.re_path) function. It basically allows you to pass a regular expression.

For the urls samples you provided you would probably want an expression like this (in your `urls.py`):

`re_path(r'^(?P<my_url>[a-z0-9/\.]+)$', your_view_function)`

This will pass a `my_url` kwarg to your view which you can then process as you want.